# Copy and paste or drag and drop plots as PDF from R in OSX?

Tags: macos, r, user-interface, graphics

Is there any device or OSX software that allows for copy/paste as PDF, like in Mathematica?

I can copy plots as bitmaps from Quartz devices in the standard GUI and (at arbitrary resolution) in RStudio, but there a frequent occasions when I want vector graphics.

### Edit:

I am aware of PDF exporting and devices, but am interested in a somewhat quicker workflow.  The purpose here is for class handouts, where I mostly just want those printouts to come out without the obvious jaggies.  It's not sensible, I know (only class notes after all), but it drives me crazy.  I quite like the `Copy As PDF` feature from Mathematica for this reason.  It works nicely for putting the same plot in the notes and in Keynote.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you pasting into?

Comment: KeyNote and TextEdit.  For more formal stuff I use LaTeX which of course requires a file anyway.

Answer (score 2):

RStudio will do it (look at Export -> Save Plot as PDF as Arun says above). Alternately you can export something as an image but choose .svg as the file type.

You can do this in base R depending on your graphics device and other stuff external to R. If you type:

```
> capabilities(what = "cairo")
 cairo 
  TRUE
```

Then you can probably export as PDF or svg outside of RStudio. See `help("svg")` for an explanation of the functions and arguments.

Edit:

If you want to copy *directly* from the x11 device to the clipboard you can do this from the Edit menu in R. I don't think you can drag directly from an x11 device to a non-x11 app (because the clipboards are different). But Edit -> Copy should work as expected and you can then paste w/ Command + V (on mac) into whatever app you like. You can test this out by running R (not RStudio) and plotting something trivial like `plot(1:10, 1:10)` then copying the output as described above into an app. It should save as a pdf file.

Comment: I think the OP wants mouse-level control though (drag and drop or copy/paste) -- seems like a bad idea to me, but it's not an insane question.

Comment: It would be nice if it worked perfectly and you were using R to just bang something out quickly for an email or something. But if you've got to go to the edit menu you might as well just hit `svg(whatever)`.

Comment: For what it's worth, one typically doesn't end up using X11 at all with R on OSX.  My sentiment about hitting `svg(whatever)` is that I avoid it.  It's fast enough creating the plot, sure, but (1) one has several context switches involved getting into the target document, and (2) if one works with script files, as I usually do, it's an edit to the file, followed by a plot, followed by another file edit.

Comment: To be pedantic, you're using X11 every time you invoke the graphics device.

Comment: @Adam: client, not server I guess. I didn't know that.

Comment: Yeah, on the client in os x and linux (I think). In practical terms this doesn't have too much of an impact except in your precise use case, because there has to be some handoff between x11 and os x. :)

Answer (score 1):

The quartz device allows copying to the clipboard and pasting into Preview.app with "New from Clipboard" results in a PDF file. So I guess I don't really understand what the problem is.

Comment: I just tested this, and I agree. I'm not sure what the problem is either. This technique maintains the vector-graphics format.